# Replace UIWebView's (loaded through a web service) <img> tag source with a local (cached) source

Tags: ios, swift, caching, uiwebview

I am working on an app (swift) where i need to load a web page inside UIWebView. Inside that UIWebView there's an `<img src="http://www.example.com/uploads/43454.jpg" />` element.

All works fine in this scenario, but the problem is that my 43454.jpg image can be of 5-10 megabytes everytime. So when the UIWebView loads it keeps on loading image for about 2 minutes. Plus this `<img>` tag can have random sources i.e. `22234.jpg`, `98734.jpg`, `33123.jpg`, and so on.

So to tackle this situation I am trying to use following approach:

1. List all possible images that we need to show in UIWebView, download and cache them (used Kingfisher library for this purpose) at aplication's startup.
2. When my UIWebView loads my URL initially, it has nothing in it's `<img>` elements `src` attribute, but have a `data-image-name="22234.jpg"` attribute-value pair.
3. Now when UIWebView finishes loading its contents, get the image name value from `data-image-name` attribute.
4. Check for that image in cache, and update the `<img>` element's src attribute with that image from cache.

This way UIWebView won't be downloading the image over and over again.

Note: Assuming that UIWebView automatically manages resource cache. All other file types `*.js`, `*.css` are being properly cached and not being loaded over and over again. The same doesn't go for images, don't know why.

If this approach seems okay, then how should I accomplish it (Swift 2.2)?

Any quick help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: My first bet would be that there is something with cache control on the server side. Could your open your site in a desktop browser and see headers that your server returns for the images, first of all [`Cache-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)? It can be done in "Dev tools" of any modern browser. You may also compare headers with the JS and CSS files that are cached. It might also help to add the headers into the questions

Comment: Seems like it will be difficult to make that work. You'd need to essentially "insert" your own cache between the UIWebView and the network.  My gut feeling is that's not possible; it's just not the sort of thing iOS supports. Can you translate the page into native iOS views? If so, then you could have more control over the image loading.

Comment: As @SergGr mentions, UIWebView has caching built in, at a more advanced level then you are likely to reimplement.  Be sure that your headers on the jpgs are not disabling caching.  If you want to prime this cache, you could likely open a WebView offscreen on startup with these images and let them load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the same situation in one of my projects. I had exactly this same scenario. I am going to paste my code here, may be it helps you figure out your solution.

1. As soon as my app loads I create an array of image URLs and pass it to `Kingfisher` library to download and cache all images (to disk).

   ```
   for url in response {
      let URL = NSURL(string: url as! String)!
      self.PlanImagesArray.append(URL)
   }

   let prefetcher = ImagePrefetcher(
   urls: self.PlanImagesArray,
   optionsInfo: nil,
   progressBlock: {
       (skippedResources, failedResources, completedResources) -> () in
           print("progress resources are prefetched: \(completedResources)")
           print("progress resources are failedResources: \(failedResources)")
           print("progress resources are skippedResources: \(skippedResources)")
               },
   completionHandler: {
       (skippedResources, failedResources, completedResources) -> () in
           print("These resources are prefetched: \(completedResources)")
           print("These resources are failedResources: \(failedResources)")
           print("These resources are skippedResources: \(skippedResources)")

           self.activityLoadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
   })

   prefetcher.start()
   ```
2. At my web view screen I initially loaded my web view and after that used following code to check for particular image in cache and if found converted it into a base64 string and put it back in `src` attribute of the  element.

   ```
   func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
       //UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
       print("webViewDidFinishLoad")

       let xlinkHref = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('background_image').getAttribute('xlink:href')")

       //print("xlink:href before = \(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('background_image').getAttribute('xlink:href')"))")

       if xlinkHref == "" {

           let imageCacheKey = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('background_image').getAttribute('data-cache-key')")
           let imageCachePath = ImageCache.defaultCache.cachePathForKey(imageCacheKey! as String)
           var strBase64:String = ""

           webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(
               "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
               "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
               "script.text = \"function setAttributeOnFly(elemName, attName, attValue) { " +
               "document.getElementById(elemName).setAttribute(attName, attValue);" +
               "}\";" +
               "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"
           )!

           if(imageCachePath != "") {

               ImageCache.defaultCache.retrieveImageForKey(imageCacheKey! as String, options: nil) { (imageCacheObject, imageCacheType) -> () in

               let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageCacheObject!, 100)!
               strBase64 = "data:image/jpg;base64," + imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn)
               webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("setAttributeOnFly('background_image', 'xlink:href', '\(strBase64)');")!    
           }

       } else {

           webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("setAttributeOnFly('background_image', 'xlink:href', '\(imageCacheKey)');")!

       }

   }
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this seems promising. although didn't try it. will get back here after giving it a test drive. thanks @Qadir

Comment: bingo..!! that's it. this one worked like a charm. your workaround did the trick. specially the base64 encoding part. love it :)

Comment: @Ali thanks. I can't even imagine I got the bounty ;) and glad to hear this worked.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're basically saying "I know what the images are ahead of time, so I don't want to wait for the UIWebView to load them from the server every time.  I want the html to use my local copies instead."

While it's a hack, my first thought was:

1. Have 2 UIWebViews: one is visible to the user and the other is hidden.
2. "Trigger" the real page in the hidden UIWebView.  When the HTML reaches you...
3. Create a new string, that is a copy of that HTML, but with the image tags that say `<img src="http://...` replaced with `<img src=\"file://...` and pointing to the correct image(s) on disk.
4. Now tell the visible UIWebView to load that HTML string you built in step 3.

Comment: What about cache? I just want to reduce the image load time. I want all images to be loaded/downloaded in the cache at the very beginning of the app (say login screen) and then go to that particular web view where one of those downloaded images are to be displayed. Once I get there my app should determine what picture this web view needs to display (will be determined from "data-key" attribute of the <img> element), and then check for that image in the cache.

Comment: If it already exists in the cache fetch it and put it in "src" attribute of the <img> element, and if not found in the cache put exact URL of that image in "src" attribute to get it downloaded.

Comment: In your answer it seems image download time (in hidden UIWebView) will have no effect (it will take actual download time). So the point remains the same. How do I reduce the image download time?